# String comparison in python not working inside the function

Tags: python, string, comparison

can someone explain me why the equality operator is not working inside this function?

```
def count_words(words_to_insert, word):

    counter = 0
    
    for i in range(0,words_to_insert):
        random_word = input("Insert a string ")
        
        print(random_word)
        print(random_word == word)
        
        if(random_word == word):
            counter +=1
            print(counter)
    
    return "You inserted the word " + word + " " + str(counter) + " times"

count_words(2, "mango")
```

[image]

If I write two strings outside the function with the same values and I compare them, the result is True

```
string_one = "mango"
string_two = "mango"
string_one == string_two
```

**OUT**

True

Comment: It looks like you're typing the quotes when you input `"mango"`, which is not equal to `mango` without the quotes.

Comment: It looks like you insert not `mango`, but `"mango"`, i.e. incl. quotes. Is this the case?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce. Running your code and entering `mango` at the prompt twice produces `True` `True` and `'You inserted the word mango 2 times'`

Comment: I ran the code and am seeing the expected output.

Comment: @G.Anderson The OP clearly typed `"mango"`, not `mango`, as the input, which explains the result.

Comment: I thought I should write the value with quotes like I am initializing a variabile and I need the quotes to say that the value is a string. Thank you so much, that was the problem!

Comment: But how does python know I am inserting a string if I don't write the quotes? Ok I saw the method input returns a string. Thank you guys

Comment: It's *always* a string; `input` always returns a string containing the characters you type. If you want a value of any other type, you need to convert the string yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not type `"` when inputting:

```
>>> Insert a string "mango"
>>> "mango"
>>> False
```

```
>>> Insert a string mango
>>> mango
>>> True
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works. Just enter mango without quotes.